# jQuery clone() issue when used with attr() method

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-ui, jquery-events

I am using the jQuery `clone()` method to clone a table row, then using the `attr()` method to change the name/id of some of the fields.  This all works well and good and if I use "view generated source" the names/IDs are getting set properly however when the generated content triggers a JavaScript event it triggers it as if it were the parent element.  For example I have an element with the name/id 'slast1' which should trigger the autocomplete method (based on the fact that it is part of the 'slast' class) and that works fine. Unfortunately when I click the same element in the generated row (in this case the element id/name is 'slast2') it triggers the autocomplete method but acts as if it was triggered from the parent element, 'slast1'.  I can't seem to find a way around this and am thinking it might be a limitation of using the `clone()` method but am hoping I am just missing something.

```
function fnAddRow(iRow)
{
  var iNewRow = iRow+1;
  $("#tblAuthors tr:last").clone(true).insertAfter("#tblAuthors tr:last");
  $("#tblAuthors tr:last #slast"+iRow).attr("name", "slast"+iNewRow);
  $("#tblAuthors tr:last #slast"+iRow).attr("id", "slast"+iNewRow);
  $("#slast"+iNewRow).val("");
}
```

The above code clones the table row and changes the attributes as I mentioned before. The code below is what gets triggered by the `keydown` event in the `slastX` element but for whatever reason the generated elements are treated as if they were the parent.

```
  $(function()
  {
    var aEmps = 
    [
<?php
echo $sEmps;
?>    
    ];

    $(".slast").bind( "keydown", function( event ) {
      if ( event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB &&
          $( this ).data( "autocomplete" ).menu.active ) 
          { event.preventDefault();}
    })
    .autocomplete({
      source: aEmps,
      close: function(event, ui)
      {
        // Split return value and store in array
        var aName = this.value.split(", ");
        // Get row #
        var iRow = this.name[this.name.length-1];
        // Populate values        
        $("#slast"+iRow).val(aName[0]);
        $("#sfirst"+iRow).val(aName[1]);
        $("#smi"+iRow).val(aName[2]);
      }
    });
  });
```

As you can see the autocomplete method should be triggered by anything with the `slast` class but for reasons I can't figure out `$(this) always = the parent ('slast1')` as opposed to `slast2` or any other generated content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using `.clone(true)` you are coping *all* `data()` and *all* events bound to that element.  Which is causing your problems.

If you switch your event binding to use `.delegate()` (or `.live()`) you should be able to fix your problem of the event being triggered.

```
var autoCompleteOptions = {
  source: aEmps,
  close: function(event, ui)
  {
    // Split return value and store in array
    var aName = this.value.split(", ");
    // Get row #
    var iRow = this.name[this.name.length-1];
    // Populate values        
    $("#slast"+iRow).val(aName[0]);
    $("#sfirst"+iRow).val(aName[1]);
    $("#smi"+iRow).val(aName[2]);
  }
};

$("#tblAuthors").delegate("tr .slast", "keydown", function(event){
    if ( event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB && 
          $( this ).data( "autocomplete" ).menu.active ) { 
     event.preventDefault();
   }
}).autocomplete(autoCompleteOptions);


function fnAddRow(iRow)
{
  //....stuff.....
  $("#tblAuthors tr:last #slast"+iRow).autocomplete(autoCompleteOptions);
  //....stuff.....
}
```

With using delegate you are binding the event to `$("#tblAuthors")` and not the `.slast` directly.

Also on a *side note*, using `delegeate` might be able to gain you a bit of performance as well in relation to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2565980/performance-jquery-live-vs-creating-specific-listeners-on-demand/2566132#2566132).

UPDATE: Mark and I went back-and-forth a lot on the solution to this, here is the final code: http://jsfiddle.net/niczak/HjCMh/1/

Comment: Absolutely outstanding response, thank you very much for taking the time to put this together.  Oddly enough firebug keeps complaining that .delegate() is not a function.  I am using jQuery 1.5.1 and jQuery UI 1.8.11 -- what am I missing?

Comment: @Nicholas, strange.  Here is a jsfiddle example on using `delegate()` http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/SRbTM/

Comment: Mark: Oy vey, the copy of jQuery that I was referencing (in our common scripts area) was 1.4. Now referring to 1.5.1 and no longer getting the error. Unfortunately I am unable to get the event to fire.  I have copied and pasted relevant code here: http://paste.ly/6Vff  -- what am I missing?

Comment: @Nicholas it looks like the `delegate()` code is outside the `$(document).ready()`, is that a typo in the paste? If not try placing that code inside the domready

Comment: @Mark: No that wasn't an error, I figured since it wasn't something that occurred on page load it could be outside of the domready.  I have modified the code (here is the updated snippet: http://paste.ly/6Vfg) but it's still not firing... Firebug isn't reporting any errors and it *looks* like it should work.

Comment: @Nicholas, could you paste some example html? As I am not seeing how `fnAddRow()` is called.

Comment: @Mark: Certainly, here is a link a snippet of the HTML: http://paste.ly/6Vfh -- I am just calling that function using a button onclick. The element that exists when the page is drawn ('slast1' which has nothing to do w/ the fnAddRow() fn) doesn't fire though which leads me to believe the problem exists outside of the add row function. Trying to tweak w/ delegate code to get "keydown" in 'slast1' to fire the autocomplete() method but have been unsuccessful thus far.

Comment: @Nicholas, try leaving the `delegate()` code in the dom ready but place the `fnAddRow()` and `var autoCompleteOptions = ...` outside since that function has to be declared outside of the scope of the `$().ready()` (since you are you using `onclick`)

Comment: @Mark: Just tried that and the event still isn't firing (at least no auto complete options show up) but when I tab out of the field ('slast1') I get the following error: 
"$(this).data("autocomplete") is undefined
$( this ).data( "autocomplete" ).menu.active ) {" -- Makes sense since autocomplete was never triggered thus the data would be undefined.  Would another complete paste of my javascript code be helpful?  Thanks again for taking all this time and going back-and-forth with me, I really appreciate it.

Comment: No problem, Could you post an example on jsfiddle.net with a sample autocomplete option that replicates the behavior?  Might be a bit easier for me to work with.

Comment: @Mark: Just an example of the autocomplete working or an example that includes the delegate approach?  If the former than here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/niczak/fMDwG/ -- the difference between this and my question is that nothing is being dynamically generated in this example.  This example: http://jsfiddle.net/niczak/Rd7Xk/ includes the delegate() approach and the actual table code. The fnAddRow() function isn't working on jsfiddle and I am not very familiar with it, is there a way to view JS errors?

Comment: @Nicholas, give this a try. http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/Rd7Xk/4/ it works for the current row and the added row. (there is an issue with autocomplete on the previous row for some reason, might warrant another question)  Hopefully this can help you out.  I have been cross eyed trying to figure out what is happening!

Comment: @Mark That is a great approach and one I was considering. I suppose by redefining the input element the event is no longer bound thus side-stepping the issue we were having earlier?  Thank you again so much for taking all the time to work this through. If you ever want to talk shop find me on Twitter (niczak) or elsewhere on the web.  Cheers!

Comment: @Mark I just merged this with my codebase and I see what you mean by rows (after adding the third) start to handle the bits of data a little funny.  I'll post a solution when I come up with one.

Comment: @Mark: I have it almost working perfectly the only problem is that the buttons that are generated w/ the cloning have an onclick event assigned to them and I can't for the life of my get unbind() or anything similar to work. I say unbind() because I have tried countless approaches to binding it to a different function (I just need to change the parameter in the function call from iRow to iNewRow) but no matter what I do it wont change that property in the element. I can change the ID fine but not the onclick event.  Any ideas?

Comment: @Mark: Sorry for all the comment spam but I have a solution that is fully working, thanks again for all of your help.  Final solution (updated fiddle) here: http://jsfiddle.net/niczak/HjCMh/1/

Answer (score 2):

Use [`live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) instead of `bind`, this should solve the problem for you.

Comment: I changed the bind() to live() so my event trigger looks like: $(".slast").live( "keydown", function( event ) { .... and I don't see any difference in the outcome.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

A helpful tool you may find useful in seeing what event handlers are bound to various elements is [Visual Event](http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/article/Visual+Event), it works as a bookmarklet and I find it invaluable at times.

In your case, it should let you see what handlers are bound to the cloned rows, if any.